# Refreshing data through constructor in Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have Ionic 2 app with one view for 3 different data sets. Data are loaded in constructor and based on variable in page params, it's decided which data set to show.

At every successful data call by observable, event handler logs success when data are loaded. But **this only works when I click/load view for a first time**. If I click for 2nd or any other time, data are not re-loaded (no log). Also, when I just console log anything, it won't show at 2nd+ click.

So I wonder **what should I change** to load data everytime and **how constructor works in this manner.**

This is how my code looks like. Jsons are called from namesListProvider.

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: '...',
})
export class ListOfNames {

   ...
    private dataListAll: Array<any> = [];
    private dataListFavourites: Array<any> = [];
    private dataListDisliked: Array<any> = [];


constructor(private nav: NavController, ...) {

    ...
    this.loadJsons();
    console.log('whatever');
  }

   loadJsons(){
    this.namesListProvider.getJsons()
    .subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        this.dataListFavourites = data[0],
        this.dataListDisliked = data[1],
        this.dataListAll = data[2]

         if (this.actualList === 'mainList') {
            this.listOfNames = this.dataListAll;
            this.swipeLeftList = this.dataListDisliked;
            this.swipeRightList = this.dataListFavourites;
         }
         else if (...) {
            ...
         }
         this.listSearchResults = this.listOfNames;


      }, err => console.log('hey, error when loading names list - ' + err),
      () => console.info('loading Jsons complete')      
    )

  }
```

Comment: What happens if you load data in ngOnInit()? You've also mentioned some  "params". Is it router or querystring params?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for are the [Lifecycle events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/nav/NavController/#lifecycle-events) from Ionic2 pages. So instead of using `ngOnInit` you can use some of the events that Ionic2 exposes:

```
Page Event        Description
----------        -----------
ionViewLoaded     Runs when the page has loaded. This event only happens once per page being created and added to the DOM. If a page leaves but is cached, then this event will not fire again on a subsequent viewing. The ionViewLoaded event is good place to put your setup code for the page.
ionViewWillEnter  Runs when the page is about to enter and become the active page.
ionViewDidEnter   Runs when the page has fully entered and is now the active page. This event will fire, whether it was the first load or a cached page.
ionViewWillLeave  Runs when the page is about to leave and no longer be the active page.
ionViewDidLeave   Runs when the page has finished leaving and is no longer the active page.
ionViewWillUnload Runs when the page is about to be destroyed and have its elements removed. 
ionViewDidUnload  Runs after the page has been destroyed and its elements have been removed.
```

In your case, you can use the `ionViewWillEnter` page event like this:

```
ionViewWillEnter {
  // This will be executed every time the page is shown ...
  this.loadJsons();
  // ...
}
```

---

**EDIT**

If you're going to obtain the data to show in that page asynchronously, since you don't know how long would it take until the data is ready, I'd recommend you to use a [loading popup](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) so the user can we aware of something happening in the background (instead of showing a blank page for a few seconds until the data is loaded). You can easily add that behaviour to your code like this:

```
// Import the LoadingController
import { LoadingController, ...} from 'ionic/angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: '...',
})
export class ListOfNames {

   ...
    private dataListAll: Array<any> = [];
    private dataListFavourites: Array<any> = [];
    private dataListDisliked: Array<any> = [];

    // Create a property to be able to create it and dismiss it from different methods of the class
    private loading: any;


  constructor(private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private nav: NavController, ...) {

    ...
    this.loadJsons();
    console.log('whatever');
  }

  ionViewWillEnter {
    // This will be executed every time the page is shown ...

    // Create the loading popup
    this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Loading...'
    });

    // Show the popup
    this.loading.present();

    // Get the data
    this.loadJsons();

    // ...
  }

  loadJsons(){
    this.namesListProvider.getJsons()
    .subscribe(
      (data:any) => {
        this.dataListFavourites = data[0],
        this.dataListDisliked = data[1],
        this.dataListAll = data[2]

         if (this.actualList === 'mainList') {
            this.listOfNames = this.dataListAll;
            this.swipeLeftList = this.dataListDisliked;
            this.swipeRightList = this.dataListFavourites;
         }
         else if (...) {
            ...
         }
         this.listSearchResults = this.listOfNames;

      }, err => console.log('hey, error when loading names list - ' + err),
      () => {

        // Dismiss the popup because data is ready
        this.loading.dismiss();

        console.info('loading Jsons complete')}
    )

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is don't do this in the constructor, use `ngOnInit()` instead.  Components are created only once, therefore the constructor will only be called when first created.

Your component class must implement the `OnInit` interface:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    templateUrl: '...',
})
export class ListOfNames implements OnInit {
    constructor(...)

    ngOnInit() {
        this.loadJsons();
    }

    private loadJsons() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, Brad. I accepted sabaferreras'es answer since it's based on Ionic, but this would work too :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm coming from Angular 2 world, not ionic, but angular 2 has the option to register callbacks on init/destory (ngInit/ngDestory).
try to move initialization to ngInit, save subscription handler, and don't forget to unsubscribe it on destory.
i think your issue related to that you are not unsubscribing.. :\